# How to check SCCM against Active Directory

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012-r2

I just took over the SCCM 2013 in my organization and it's pretty much not in a organised way. I need to start doing some house keeping with my limited knowledge on SCCM.

Currently there are 16 collection across a month for patching and I can't seem to find out which servers are added or not added into the collection. I also can't seem to really know if they are in the right collection.

How do you all do your checks against the AD to ensure servers are added to SCCM collection and in the right ones ? 
How do you all ensure the patches are installed in all VMs ?

I come across two PS script below but it seems that it require many manual work.

The first PS script I seen is this whichs gets computer in each Collection.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Computers-in-SCCM-948e666f

Second script gather the SCCM collections membership of a given computer or user.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-SCCM-collection-of-8bfdf62c

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the built-in or custom reports in ConfigMgr to achieve your goals.

1. In your scenarios, if you want to know the resources in each collection, you can just run the report: **Monitoring->Reporting->Software Distribution-Collections->All Resources in a specific collection.**

If you want to know the collections of each resources, you can create a custom report (the guide how to create a custom report cab be found [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gary_simmons_mcs/2013/12/09/creating-a-custom-report-for-system-center-2012-r2-configuration-manager-part-1/)) or simply do write a SQL query like following:

```
select distinct FCM.Name ResName,Col.Name ColName from 
v_FullCollectionMembership FCM
inner join v_Collection Col
on FCM.CollectionID=Col.CollectionID
order by ResName
```

2. While you can use the deployments node and the Software Updates node in ConfigMgr to check the deployment status and the compliance status, it is still recommended to use the Reports because it is more accurate and flexible. You can use the **Update Compliance reports** like below to get the compliance status for each computer in your environment.

[image]